# Vue.js: how to have routing across 3 columns

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to set up an page resembling:

```
   ========================================================================
   +    Nav        +    Items      +          Individual Item             +
   +---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+
   +   * Cats      +     List      +         Individual Selected          +
   +   * Dogs      +      Of       +                Cat                   +
   +               +     Cats      +                 OR                   +
   +               +      OR       +                Dog                   +
   +               +     Dogs      +                                      +
   +               +               +                                      +
   +               +               +                                      +
   ========================================================================
```

Usage example: Select 'Cats' in the 'Nav' column => retrieve a list of Cats (via REST/JSON) into the 'Items' column; Select an individual Cat from the list => retrieve an individual Cat (via REST/JSON) into the "Individual Item" column.

This looks like an application of Nested Routes (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) but my google-fu must be weak and I can't find a 3-level example like this anywhere.

It is easy to arrange an either/or approach where a single right-hand column renders either "List of Items" or 'Item.'

I have tried to use named views but I get to a point where I have 3 columns but when I render an 'Item' component, then the "List of Items" column is emptied.

It may be that I need to arrange to render both "List of Items" and 'Items' column at the same time (via 'components' in my router config) BUT these are remote REST calls so this is too heavyweight to be practical. Maybe 'computed' or 'watched' properties will assist in this case?

Is there an example of this three-level navigation somewhere?

Any help appreciated.

Edit:

this is the sort of thing I thought would be needed:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 bg-light sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-sticky">
      <h3 class="h3 pl-3">Actions</h3>
      <navigation />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 ml-auto bg-info px-3">
    <router-view />
  </div>
  <div class="col-7 bg-warning px-3">
    <router-view name="entity" />
  </div>
</div>
```

...

```
{
  path: 'persons',
  component: httpVueLoader('persons.vue'),
  children: [
      {
          path: 'person/:id',
          components: {
            default: httpVueLoader('persons.vue'),
            entity: httpVueLoader('person.vue')
          }
      }
  ]
},
```

Comment: if need a "3rd" layer, just add the `children` property to a child route.

Comment: If I just do that, I end up with the situation where my "List if Items" column is empty. I've edited the question to show the sort of thing I have tried...

Comment: I was wondering what is the problem with using two dynamic segments.
`path: '../:person/:id',`

Here person could be `cat` or `dog` and then `id` would be the selected cat or dog.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the routing aspect, but with the rendering: here I have components that aren't really nested children, but which do have dependencies.

Comment: quite honestly, you can just make regular routes, the whole child routes is nice but never necessary it's really sytnactic sugar, instead of writing "/parent/child" you just write "child"